# How does $x=2$ form a 2-Dimensional Space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Today when professor solving old exam questions one question like;

```
Vectors satisfying x=2 equation form a -- dimensional space in R^3.
```

And he said blank will be 2-D. I don't understand. Isn't it $x=2$ just a line?

Comment: Both are wrong.  $\{(x,y,z)~:~x=2,~y,z\in\Bbb R\}$ does not form a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ (*it is not closed under addition, is not closed under scalar multiplication and does not contain the zero vector*).  It will form an **affine** space however, and that affine space will be two-dimensional.  Note that every vector in the set can be written in the form $(2,0,0) + s(0,1,0)+t(0,0,1)$

Comment: So because he said R^3, we think equation has also y and z compenent right? If it is R^4, will  x=2 be form a volume?

Comment: Yes.  The fact he said $\Bbb R^3$ is precisely what clues us in to there being three components in the vectors we are referring to (*and those three components are traditionally named $x,y,$ and $z$ respectively*)

Comment: Thank you so much. I want to give a '+' but my reputation doesn't allow this (:.

Comment: What your professor said might be interpreted as meaning that the equation $x=2$ defines a 2-dimensional *affine* subspace, i.e. an affine plane.